# Error when I try to publish a book with bookdown::publish_book()

Tags: r, ssl, bookdown

I try to publish my book with bookdown. I use the following command:

```
bookdown::publish_book()
```

It worked well last week but now I get the following error message:

```
You do not currently have a bookdown.org publishing account configured on 
this system.
Would you like to configure one now? [Y/n]: Y
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol 
version
Timing stopped at: 0 0 0.1
```

I am on Windows 10, RStudio version 1.1.456 anr R 3.5, and bookdown 0.7.18.

I have tried to delete the previous version of the book. I also tried to publish the bookdown-demo instead of my own book to see if my problem is with my book but I got the same erro message. I have tried the stable version of bookdown and the devlopment version and I got the same message.

I have absolutely no idea what does SSL and routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol mean.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thjs seems to be an SSL issue. Github shows 0.7 as latest release. Did you build from latest source?

Comment: Yes, This seems to be SSL issue but I don't understand your answer. Github shows 0.7 as latest release of what? SSL? I have no idea what it is. I have tried to find which SSL I have on my computer and I think I have SSL 3.0. I added the picture in the main post.

Comment: We are trying to fix it. You may keep an eye on https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/628. Thanks!

Comment: Should be resolved now. Could you retry publishing to bookdown.org? Thanks!

Comment: It works now! Thanks.